# Android apk in bin directory different from one installed on device

Tags: android, apk

Today I noticed a strange thing, the apk in bin directory is different from the one installed on device/emulator. Even after clean and build, the apks are different.

Ok fine I renamed/re-factored the project from ProjectV0.3 to ProjectV0.4 and the bin now contains ProjectV0.4.apk, but the apk that gets installed on device/emulator is ProjectV0.3.

How could this happen? After clean and build, shouldn't a new apk be generated and installed on devices?

Am using Eclipse 4.2, and android API level 18(V4.3).

Comment: delete the app and all its references from the device and try. I had this issue in Flash Builder for some reason the USB debugger was installation the old app.

Comment: "build" does not trigger installation, you probably need the "run" command for that, or explicitly install yourself using adb from the command line.

Comment: @Jaan I tried, but the result is still the same.

Comment: please check if you have the apk file somewhere else in your project too. it maybe in the some other directory as well. If I were you, I would search my computer to find the ProjectV0.3 and delete them from everywhere and see if that could help, it is a kinda troubleshooting came in mind, the rest , I dont see any reason doing this way. it should be ok. just try this and see.

Comment: @Jaan There was one found in the strings.xml, and after changing it to ProjectV0.4, the problem got resolved. Thanks a lot.

Comment: cool, sometimes stuff hide, that is good that you found it. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Jaan, on searching the whole project for "ProjectV0.3" text, it was found in the string.xml file under res->values folder. Changing the text to "ProjectV0.4" solved the problem.